# Can I read an lp file into pulp.LpProblem object

Tags: python, pulp

I have a very big LP problem saved as an lp file. Is there a way I can read that file as a LpProblem object with PuLP? It took a lot of time to build that problem (around 7 hours) and I just want to use a code I have to add more constraints to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work fine for me loading the variables and the instance/model.

```
import pulp

var, model = pulp.LpProblem.fromMPS('my_file.mps')
```

Comment: This is the solution a was looking for then. This was not available on pulp 1.6.5 but it is in pulp 2.5. [How to import and export models in PuLP](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/guides/how_to_export_models.html?highlight=frommps)

Comment: Lp format =! Mps format

Answer (score 3):

Having run into this same problem (and numerous others) with PuLP, a group of linear-solving, open-source-minded engineers over at Freewheel have started to develop Flipy, a Python package specializing in linear programming. Some key features: runtime performance and a READ LP function. Feel free to check it out over at https://github.com/freewheel/flipy

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, there is no support for reading files within pulp.

The docs [here](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/technical/pulp.html) show that there is a writeLP-method (which is the core-functionality needed for all those solvers; pulp seems to be heavily based on write lp -> call solver on lp-file), but no read/load method.

One possible reason, despite some extra work which won't be used by many users, could be the fact, that people might use this to load just any lp-file. This would be problematic as different solvers are using different standards (even if the core-idea of the format is the same).

*Keep in mind, that it's possible* that the lp-format enforces some assumptions which needs a transformation of your constraints. This means, that some read-method based on the lp-file never can give you back your original formulation, but just something equivalent. This further enhances the complexity of this task.

It might be possible to store some LpProblem using Python's in-build serialization like pickle (different approach: save the internal-state from a python-perspective). But this depends a bit on the implementation and also won't help in your use-case.

Comment: Thank you. That totally makes sense. It seems I'll have to do as you recommend: generate again the LpProblem (another 7 hours!) and store it as it is being built.

Comment: But try this with some smaller example first to see if pickle thinks it's pickable.

Comment: Yup building a model from an lp file will be difficult.  I would recommend that you look here for tips on how to decrease your build time.
http://www.stuartmitchell.com/journal/2012/2/3/my-top-n-tips-for-python-coding-in-optimisation-1.html

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me.

1. Install cplex and docplex with pip.
2. Read LP file, export as MPS and read from MPS again.

```
import pulp as pl
import docplex.mp.model as cpx
import docplex.mp.model_reader as cpxreader


m = cpxreader.ModelReader.read(
    r'file.lp')
m.export_as_mps(
    path=r'file.mps')

var, model = pl.LpProblem.fromMPS(
    r'file.mps')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [Python-MIP](https://python-mip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) to be a good solution for reading LP files in Python. It correctly reads integer/binary variables as well, while for example flipy does not. It is also easier to use than the Python APIs of IBM CPLEX or Gurobi.